# S3 standard storage list by curent date

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'd to ask how to filter the standard storage of s3 bucket filtering by current date only.

**using this command:**

> aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket videos --prefix Genre --query
>   "Contents[?StorageClass=='STANDARD'].Key" --output text | sed
>   's/\t/\n/g'

Comment: You mean objects added to the bucket today or object names that has current date?

Comment: objects added to the bucket today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the command to filter object based on **`LastModified`** attribute.

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket videos --prefix Genre --query "Contents[?LastModified>'2017-03-14T00:00:00.000Z'].Key" --output text | sed 's/\t/\n/g'
```